# ImportError - Django and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I'm attempting to set up mod_wsgi with Django and Apache locally on a Fedora 16 machine.  I run into the error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'cat.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named cat.settings
```

I realize there are a few other questions about this - but their solutions have not fixed this error.  I appreciate any help or ideas you may have regarding the message!

--

Here's a bit of insight into my set-up:

- Receiving 500 Internal Server Error at localhost.
- My directory is: /home/name/src/django/animals/cat (where the cat directory contains an __init__.py and a settings.py file.
- I have one application folder in the cat directory, named catOne - it also contains an __init__.py file.
- My wsgi file looks like this:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/name/src/django/animals/cat')
sys.path.append('/home/name/src/django/animals')

sys.stderr.write('\n'.join(sys.path))

root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
sys.path.insert(0, root)

packages = os.path.join(root, 'environ/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, packages)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'cat.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

- The permissions on the settings and init files are 755, but I've also tried 777 without success.
- My sys.path looks like:

```
/var/www
/usr/lib/python27.zip
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gst-0.10
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info
/home/name/src/django/animals/cat
/home/name/src/django/animals
```

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Have you checked the security profiles of apache in Fedora? They might be blocking access of apache to that directory anyway... fast to check if you attempt a read from your wsgi file to a file on that directory. Last time I checked I remember there were all kind of annoying security thingies in Fedora.

Comment: I haven't - do you have a resource or command suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: First check that apache/mod_wsgi effectively can access the directory. Try for example 'cat "the ants are brown" > /home/name/src/django/animals/cat/test.txt' from the command line, and then in your wsgi config see what happens when you do print( open("/home/name/src/django/animals/cat/test.txt").read() ). If you don't get the ants in the apache log, but some error instead, then SELinux is probably blocking apache. Check this then http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux_FAQ

Comment: You were right - it was SELinux.  Thanks very much - I'll append an answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELinux was causing an issue accessing the file.  This probably isn't the best way, but I disabled it entirely by editing the /etc/selinux/config file.  Change SELINUX=enforcing to SELINUX=disabled.

Again, there are probably finer grain controls for changing SELinux so disable at your own peril.